# How do I resize textfield width as per size of the widget above it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I resize the textfield width as per the width of the red container in the `Custom` widget .The red container will actually contain Image widget and it will be inside `Flexible` widget which will resize it whenever keyboard appears.

This is the codeblock :-

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageWithState createState() => HomePageWithState();
}

class HomePageWithState extends State<HomePage> {
  String path = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test "),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [Custom()],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Select',
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Custom extends StatelessWidget {
  Face({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  // final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 250,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
           Container(
             child: TextField(
               // controller: _controller,
               decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'No Text'),
             ),
           ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your Text widget inside FittedBox().

Something like this:

```
FittedBox(child: Text('Your text goes here'));
```